# Select operator in database

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm, sorting

Given a dataset D_{26xn} with columns named from [a-z] (no of columns is just an example) and n observations. Each column (x) has (r_x) unique states. Rows in D are sorted with descending priority on columns [a-z].

Task: For columns (b, j, p) return indexes of rows such that indexes of identical rows are consecutive. Ordering among rows with different set of values for (b, j, p) is immaterial.

Can there a solution with a complexity of O(n)?

Sol1: Columns (b, j ,p) can be sorted and respective can be returned indexes. But the complexity for this solution is O(no_columns*nlog(n)).

Sol2: Iterate over each row and hash them. But Hashing would more expensive practically.

Answer (score 0):

> Can there a solution with a complexity of O(n)?

Seems unlikely. Would you get such solution, you'd be able to sort arbitrary key length data in O(n).